# Is there a way to cast data type of object to number in python 3

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, type-conversion, correlation

I have a dataframe which includes around 20 columns. There is one column named outcomes, the data type is object and it contains values such as 'death' and 'alive'. I want to compute the correlation between the input and this outcome data. I use Python3. I imported pandas and numpy already. I want to convert 'death' to 1 and 'alive' to 0, so I can compute the correlation between age with this outcome. 
Is there a way to do so? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: `df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].eq('death').astype(int)`.

Comment: Thank you but it did not work. I am using jupyter notebook. and pandas can not handle it
pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

Answer (score 4):

Try [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df.outcomes.map({'death': 1, 'alive': 0})
```

This will return a series with numeric values.

Comment: Thank you but It did not work.  Pandas cast the data into NaN, and the data type now is float64